# Displaying which rows are duplicates in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataset in a txt file that has thousands of lines, each row containing 6 entries:

> 27.952555 4.023447 61.275883 -0.305102 -0.869921 -1.222882
>
> 27.952555 4.617039 60.936607 -0.296737 -0.369152 -1.435724

Is there a way I can check if there are any identical rows in R, such as if I came across this line below?

> 27.952555 4.023447 61.275883 -0.305102 -0.869921 -1.222882
>
> 27.952555 4.617039 60.936607 -0.296737 -0.369152 -1.435724...
>
> 27.952555 4.023447 61.275883 -0.305102 -0.869921 -1.222882

How to display this duplicate?
`

Comment: Check `?duplicated`.

Comment: In that link, the OP wants to remove rows. I don't want to remove any rows.

Comment: How are you reading the file into R?

Comment: @user4352158 - then duplicated will give you what you want - `df[duplicated(df),]`

Comment: Or `which(duplicated(df))` if you just want the line numbers

Answer (score 2):

Use `duplicated`:

```
duplicated(iris)
#   [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [49] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [61] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [73] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [85] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [97] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [109] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [121] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [133] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [145] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Possibly in tandem with `which` to see row numbers:

```
which(duplicated(iris))
# [1] 143
```

Or `[` extraction to see the rows themselves:

```
iris[duplicated(iris),]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
```